# Filebrowser in HUE not working, uploads fail for user

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hue, webhdfs

The Error I see when I try to upload as any user reports:

**"Failed to obtain user group information: org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException: User: hadoop is not allowed to impersonate hue"**

I'm not sure what to do... 
I have changed the psuedo_distribution file in hue, and added proxy group hdfs and hadoop to the hadoop core-site.xml

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is using 'hadoop' instead of 'hue'. Which Hue distribution are you using? You should not need to modify hue.ini file by default.

How to [configure Hue for HDFS](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh_hue_configure.html#topic_15_4_1_unique_1):

```
 WebHDFS: Add to core-site.xml:

<!-- Hue WebHDFS proxy user setting -->
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Temporarily I got taken off of this project-- I'll have to return to it soon!  I'm a big-time data analysis guy, and I'd love to have this working.  So far my efforts have not enabled me to work with files, because of HUE user permissions.  It took way too long to get it working :(

Comment: We recommend Cloudera Manager for setting up everything in 10 minutes http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-how-to-create-a-real-hadoop-cluster-in-10-minutes/ ;0)